# Macbook Pro Booting Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake

I have a Macbook Pro 15" Retina Mid 2014.
Off late, whenever i put my mac to sleep and when i try to wake it up, it doesnt! I need restart it, but then it takes lot of time and just hangs at the end with the Apple logo and the status bar as complete!
I then have to restart with Command+Option+p+r and then wait for 2 beeps and then finally it starts!
Any advise to sort this out would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If the above don't work, which I imagine resetting the NVRAM won't since that's what you do each time, you can try the following:

- Your Mac might be in Safe Sleep. To [wake from Safe Sleep](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201635), connect
  your Mac to its power adapter and press the power button. Make sure
  that your Mac isn't turned off. If your MacBook Pro still won't wake
  up, follow these steps to turn off Power Nap:
- Press and hold the power button to turn off your Mac. Wait a few
  seconds, then press the power button again to turn your Mac back on.

  - After your Mac starts up, choose Apple logo in top-left corner > System Preferences,
    then click Energy Saver. Click the Battery tab and deselect Enable
    Power Nap while on battery power. Click the Power Adapter tab and
    deselect Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it was always "deselected"

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already reset the NVRAM, but the first thing I'd try is to reset **both** the NVRAM and SMC in that order. Before following the steps below, ensure you have no external hardware connected and make sure you use the **built-in keyboard**.

**Reset the NVRAM**

Your Mac uses Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Here’s how to reset the NVRAM on your particular MBP:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime for the second time.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

Once done, proceed to resetting the SMC as well.

**Reset the SMC**

To reset the System management Controller on your particular MBP, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd> and hold all these down for at least 10 seconds
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

After resetting both the NVRAM and SMC, use your computer to determine if the issue still persists.

If it does, then it's time to check the status of your battery.

**Check battery status**

1. Ensure your MacBook is connected to a power source
2. Go to Apple > About This Mac
3. Ensure you have the Overview tab selected
4. Click on the System Report... button
5. After the System Information window appears, click on the Power option (it's listed in the lefthand menu within the Hardware section)
6. Now on the righthand side take note of the following items:

   - Under **Charge Information:** *Charging* and *Full Charge Capacity*
   - Under **Health Information:** *Cycle Count* and *Condition*

Now report back the results via the comment option below.

---

**[UPDATE]**

Since the SMC reset hasn't resolved this (as one would expect), your battery status is most likely key to your problem.

MacBook Pro batteries have a life expectancy at or around 1,000 cycles.  It's not uncommon for batteries to exceed or fall short of this number; as every user is different in terms of what they use their computers for and how/when they're using AC power etc. So the 1,000 cycles is just an estimation of how long it can last. But, in your case, the battery has lasted 1,500 cycles and this is 50% more than its life expectancy. To be frank, I'm surprised the status is Replace Soon instead of Replace Now or Service Battery.

However, since it is still showing Replace Soon, you could test for how your MBP behaves during Safe Mode.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window
5. Now log into your Mac and (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice)
6. Now test to see if your MacBook wakes up normally after you've put it to sleep
7. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
8. Once again, test to see if your Mac wakes up normally after you've put it to sleep

If you find that your MacBook still doesn't wake up while in Safe Mode or when logged in normally afterwards, then proceed to Running Apple Diagnostics below.

If on the other hand you find that your MacBook does wake up from sleep in Safe Mode, but still doesn't when you're logged in normally, then let me know and we'll troubleshoot further.

**Running Apple Diagnostics**

Your model MBP uses **Apple Diagnostics** to test its hardware. You can do this as follows:

1. Fully shut down your MBP
2. Restart your MBP
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Comment: Hi! I have tried the SMC thing, didn't work! The battery information is as below: Charge Information:
  Charge Remaining (mAh): 1117
  Fully Charged: No
  Charging: Yes
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5970
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count: 1500
  Condition: Replace Soon

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I've updated my answer.